# Magento2 one page success error

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, onepage-checkout, order-success-page, purchase-order

I get blank page when I place order, on success page I have 500 error and it is blank. I can see the order on admin panel and buyer panel, but status is pending.
Also i increased PHP memory limit. I can not even go to bank payment because of this issue. Also COD has this issue too

This is my exception log on COD:

```
 [2019-12-08 04:52:20] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\NotFound$
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Mer$
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Mer$
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Mer$
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Mer$
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Mer$
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Conf$
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Conf$
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Conf$
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Conf$
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Pa$
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/L$
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/$
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/$
#13 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/$
#14 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model$
#15 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/$
#16 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/$
```

Comment: See Server and Magento errors

Comment: Please Check exception log and let me know the error

Comment: @SaneerLadani, I updated my question. thanks a lot

Comment: Log text does not showing fully at here .....`vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Mer`

Comment: @MGPM Can you please update your question with the full error. because some text does not show in your question